# Multiple wordpress installations on 1 AWS EC2 instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to have several wordpresssites on one EC2 instance and folled this tutorial:

[Running Multiple Sites on EC2 Instance](http://nouveauframework.org/blog/vhosts-running-multiple-sites-on-a-single-aws-ec2-instance/)

So far, so good, it looks, that all works pretty fine, but now I have this folder:

/var/www/vhosts/webillusions.it

I tried to put a index.html file into /var/www/vhosts/webillusions.it, but if I want to test it in a browser like my-public-ip/vhosts/webillusions.it it says, that "the requested URL /vhosts/webillusions.it was not found on this server."

In the html folder it works like a charme, but why not with my vhosts folder?

I've created in the html folder a folder called website and I can access it easily with my-public-ip/website, perhaps I need to configure the php.ini for the standard html folder, but that isn't described in the tutorial and I am a totally newbie, any help would be appreciated.

Thx

Comment: Are you using Apache?

Comment: Yes, sure, I've installed a EC2 instance with Amazon Linux Ami